# How can I configure WordPress multisite from the command line?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to install WordPress with multisite support.  All of the walkthroughs I've found require pointing a browser at wp-admin after updating wp-config.php.  This process is failing repeatedly with these errors:

```
wp_1_posts: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_posts' doesn't exist
wp_1_comments: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_comments' doesn't exist
wp_1_links: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_links' doesn't exist
wp_1_options: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_options' doesn't exist
wp_1_postmeta: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_postmeta' doesn't exist
wp_1_terms: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_terms' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_taxonomy: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_relationships: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_term_relationships' doesn't exist
wp_1_termmeta: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_termmeta' doesn't exist
wp_1_commentmeta: Table 'wp_db.wp_1_commentmeta' doesn't exist
```

I'd like to understand exactly what is going on, not push magic buttons in a browser.  Is there a way to set up WordPress and MySQL with support for multisite completely from the command line?

Comment: The wp-cli has the command that you are looking for `wp core multisite-install`. When you get a chance please take a look in the documentation [WP-CLI documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-install/)

Comment: This is weird.  Multisite's first "extra" site typically has the table name prefix "wp_2_", not "wp_1_".   Any, there's quite a lot going on behind the scenes whether you push buttons or use wp-cli.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I ran "wp core multisite-install" on a fresh database and, after explicitly resetting the admin password, everything seems to be working.
If you change your comment to an answer I'll happily mark it as correct.